# Displaying message at empty node in blackberry xml parsing

Tags: blackberry, xml-parsing, nodes

In parsing an XML result in a blackberry application, which returns nodes in the form;

```xml
<searches> 
<search id ='1234'>
<name> somename </name>
<address> some address </address>
<sector> some sector </sector>
<contacts> 12345, me@me.com </contacts>
<searches>
```

when a search is made which doesn't have any matches the result is returned empty, that is;

```xml
<name></name>
<address></address>
<sector></sector> 
<contacts></contacts>
```

don't return with the results. It appears just as `<searches></searches>` . How do I specify a dialog alert in such cases when the search results return just `<searches></searches>`

here is my Http connection attached with the parser.

```java
   try{
         HttpConnection connection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open("http://someurl.xml",Connector.READ_WRITE);
         URLEncodedPostData postData = new URLEncodedPostData(URLEncodedPostData.DEFAULT_CHARSET, false);
         postData.append("username", "someusername");
         postData.append("password", "somepassword");
         postData.append("term", word);
         connection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
         connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
         OutputStream requestOut = connection.openOutputStream();
         requestOut.write(postData.getBytes());
         connection.getHeaderField("Content-type"); 
         DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         docBuilder.isValidating();
         InputStream detailIn = connection.openInputStream();
         doc = docBuilder.parse(detailIn);
         requestOut.close();
         connection.close(); 
         NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
         NodeList list1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("address");
         NodeList list2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("sector");
         NodeList list3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("contacts");
         callback(list,list1,list2,list3);
         requestOut.close();
         connection.close();
     }
     catch(Exception ex){
         System.out.println(ex.toString());
     }
```

do I use if's or for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the Eclipse plug-in in front of me (so I can't test this code), but something like this should work:

```java
doc = docBuilder.parse(detailIn);
requestOut.close();
connection.close(); 
NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("name");
NodeList list1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("address");
NodeList list2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("sector"); 
NodeList list3 = doc.getElementsByTagName("contacts");
if (list == null || list.getLength() == 0) {
    // no results, so post an alert on the UI thread
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Dialog.alert("No results found!");
        }
    });
}
```

This only tests the existence of the `name` element, assuming that if `name` is missing, so will the others (address, sector, and contacts).  If that's not true for your application, you could choose to make the `if` statement check `list1`, `list2`, and `list3` also.

Comment: I put  `callback(list,list1,list2,list3);`  in the `else` clause. it works according to the method i typed for it, that is, it opens a new page if results are found. but `Dialog.alert("No results found!");` doesnt appear if results are not found. But fortunately it doesnt open an empty page like it used to, just that the dialog box doesnt open which is really important.

Comment: @michael92, sorry about that.  Even though you didn't explicitly post this code, I probably should have assumed that you were running your HTTP connection code on a background thread.  Is that right?  If so, you should make sure to post your `Dialog.alert()` call on the UI thread.  I've updated my answer to show that.  The above code should now be appropriate to be run on a background/worker thread.

Comment: you're a lifesaver. Wish i could give you 10 points for that  :)